# Wifi driver installation in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, madwifi

I installed ubuntu on my computer (rog zephyrus g14) and found that the wifi driver is not installed properly. with `ifconfig` only shows `lo`, but I see that my computer has a network card when I look at the hardware list with `lspci`, so how do I install the appropriate driver on my computer, and how do I find the appropriate driver file. I think my network card model is `Intel Corporation Device[8086:2723] (rev 1a)`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually observed when the computer is relatively newer model while the OS is older.
This might not be the best solution but one can try this to by-pass the blockage.
Execute all of the following steps:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Download linux-firmware_1.173.18_all.deb and install using DPKG

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.173.18_all.deb
sudo reboot
```

After your system boots up again, you can try `iwconfig` command on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you tried to disable fastboot on BIOS, because it would effect some devices failing. And if still not working I recommend you to install AX200 driver from the official website:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless.html